# OpenGL ES 2.0 and games

Tags: opengl

I tried installing Angry Birds but found that it throws an error: "OpenGL ES not detected. "

I have a relatively old PC configuration here:

- Intel Pentium 4 2.0 GHz

  - 1 GB DDR RAM
  - 56 MB onboard graphics card.

Is it possible to run OpenGL ES 2.0 on this machine? Do I have to update my computer or can I still run modern games on this machine?

Comment: what OS? I'm assuming windows, but mentioning what version specifically would help

Answer (score 1):

In theory opengl support is dependent on your drivers - in windows, its bundled into the hardware specific drivers as an [installable client driver](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/mswindows.htm#0040), and its supported by mesa on linux. [OpenGL 2.0 has been out for the past 5 years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opengl#OpenGL_2.0), so, most semi-modern video cards should support it.

By the [speed of the system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_4#Northwood), i'm assuming its a 2000ish era system, and it predates opengl 2.0. Upgrading the driver MIGHT work (but i doubt it somewhat - drivers for a system that old would be hard to find, and not maintained. ) or a more serious fix would be to find a semi modern PCI based card - unless it has PCI-e and switch to discrete graphics.

With a 56 mb onboard graphics card... modern games are implausible. Even the x3100, which could use a whopping 384 mb of ram (and is about 4-5 years old) can't really handle much outside casual gaming -its on the verge of being able to run source based games (and source scales VERY well) but can't. A video card update should give your system a few more years, IMO